# Usage of definite articles with things described with "that"-clauses

Tags: sentence-meaning, articles, definite-article

> 1. I don't like films that don't have happy endings.
> 2. I don't like the films that don't have happy endings.

My grammar book says sentence 1 is the correct answer. But I don't get it. I think the second one should be the answer. Aren't we talking about some specific films?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly doesn't sound like we're talking about any specific films that you and your reader might have in mind. If I say that I don't like red cars, it means that I don't like cars that are red. There is no specificity in that statement whatsoever. All it says is that there are cars of different colors and I just don't happen to like ones that are red. A "that" clause does not necessitate the use of a definite article.

Examples:

> — Do you want to buy a car? But what color do you want your car to be?
>   — Any color will do except red. I just don't like **cars that are red**.
>
> — What movies do you not like to watch?
>   — I don't like to watch **movies that are about violence**.

I guess, technically speaking, the statements *red cars* and *cars that are red* are indeed a little bit more specific than just *cars*, but they are still no more familiar than *cars*. Definite articles are used when you have some sort of familiarity or "preknowledge" of the things that you are talking about.

Comment: Okey so what about this one? "Someone gave me a book about history of modern art" or "Someone gave me a book about the history of modern art"

Comment: @TalhaÖzden That is specific. But general statements do not take the: I dislike questions about determiners. :) no the.

Comment: That's a completely different question, actually. All I can say is that out of the two choices you've got there, **the history of modern art** is the correct one because in this case that "history" that we're talking about is a very specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Aren't we talking about some specific films?.

Can you (or a party in the conversation) name those specific films?

If not, then you aren't talking about specific films, but films in general.  Thus, no article.